# Can't connect to node app on kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've just finished Google's [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-kubernetes-engine) on how to implement continuous integration for a Go app on Kubernetes using Jenkins, and it works great. I'm now trying to do the same thing with a Node app that is served on port 3001, but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"gceme-frontend\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "gceme-frontend",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 404
}
```

The only thing I've changed on the routing side is having the load balancer point to 3001 instead of 80, since that's where the Node app is listening. I have a very strong feeling that the error is somewhere in the .yaml files.

My node server (relevant part):

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
```

frontend-dev.yaml: (this is applied to the dev environment)

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: gceme-frontend-dev
spec:
  replicas: 
  template:
    metadata:
      name: frontend
      labels:
        app: gceme
        role: frontend
        env: dev
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3001
            protocol: TCP
```

services/frontend.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: gceme-frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
      #THIS PORT ACTUALLY GOES IN THE URL: i.e. gcme-frontend: ****
      #when it says "no endpoints available for service, that doesn't mean this one is wrong, it means that target port is not working not exist"
    port: 80
      #matches port and -port in frontend-*.yaml
    targetPort: 3001
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: gceme
    role: frontend
```

Jenkinsfile (for dev branches, which is what I'm trying to get working)

```
sh("kubectl get ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME} || kubectl create ns ${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
// Don't use public load balancing for development branches
sh("sed -i.bak 's#LoadBalancer#ClusterIP#' ./k8s/services/frontend.yaml")
sh("sed -i.bak 's#gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/gceme:1.0.0#${imageTag}#' ./k8s/dev/*.yaml")
sh("kubectl --namespace=${env.BRANCH_NAME} apply -f k8s/services/")
sh("kubectl --namespace=${env.BRANCH_NAME} apply -f k8s/dev/")
echo 'To access your environment run `kubectl proxy`'
echo "Then access your service via http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/${env.BRANCH_NAME}/services/${feSvcName}:80/"
```

Comment: Share the Deployment files that are failing, not the former ones that did work. Also, can you paste the output of kubectl describe deploy gceme`?

Comment: Updated with new logs and my actual files.

Comment: What about `kubectl --namespace=production logs deploy/gceme-frontend-production`? Anything useful there?

Comment: After doing more experimenting, it looks like the proxy isn't the issue - I found that a localhost URL didn't work directly, but had to be pasted into the GCP terminal to generate a URL that properly routed to where the app is hosted. I've updated accordingly, as I believe I've found the real issue now.

Comment: Hi @ArtemZakharov, can you post your solution as an answer to this question which will benefit the community and make it more visible to anyone who has similar issue in future?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating Service or Ingress resources to  expose your application to the outside world?

See tutorials:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

which have working examples you can copy and modify.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually starting from a working example based on this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-kubernetes-engine I'm just trying to replace the Go app with my Node one.